# Output a diff to command line when rebase fails instead of modifying files

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

When git rebase fails, it modifies the conflicting files, which is not really handy. Is there a way, how to stop git rebase to do that?

When git rebase fails, user obviously wants to get some diff (target x patch) of the conflicting lines outputted into command line. How to achieve this?

Note: Because of these two issues I avoid git rebase since I first learned to use git. I derive new branch from target and use `git cherry pick -X theirs` (forced cherry-pick). After that I resolve issues using `git diff` and `git commit --amend`, which is not straightforward, but works for me better than git rebase.

Comment: You can `git rebase --abort` to undo the changes to the conflicting files. But the files are modified to show the conflicting changes, so I don't understand what you want git to do. Maybe the `merge.conflictStyle` option set to `diff3` would help?

Comment: Not to edit files when rebase conflict. I don't want any of these weird markers to be inputted into a file when unsuccessful rebase was run. I want to output the conflicted diff into command line, not to the files.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The files you want are in the index, in the staging slots reserved for merge conflicts.

#### Long

> When git rebase fails, it modifies the conflicting files, which is not really handy. Is there a way, how to stop git rebase to do that?

No.

But there's much more to it than this.  Rebase is, essentially, a series of `git cherry-pick` operations, and each cherry-pick is actually a merge—a three-way merge, with an unusual merge base given the two left / local / `HEAD` / `--ours` and right / remote / other / `--theirs` commits.

Consider this "before rebase" and "after rebase" sequence:

```
[before rebase]

...--o--*--A--B--C   <-- yourbranch
         \
          D--E   <-- target

[after rebase]

...--o--*--A--B--C   [mostly abandoned]
         \
          D--E   <-- target
              \
               A'-B'-C'  <-- yourbranch
```

To get from the "before" to the after", Git starts by checking out commit `E` (as a detached HEAD).  It then runs `git cherry-pick <hash-of-A>`.

This cherry-pick operation runs a merge, with the merge base being commit `*`, the `--ours` or `HEAD` commit being commit `E`, and the `--theirs` commit being commit `A`.

Like all merges, the actual merge for each file takes place in the *index*, using the three *merging staging slots*.  These are numbered: slot 1 is for the merge base, slot 2 is for the `--ours` version, and slot 3 is for the `--theirs` version.

If the merge goes well, the final merged result is copied to slot zero, wiping out the slot 1-3 entries, and Git proceeds on.  If not, the *work-tree* version of the file is marked up in the way that you don't want.  However, *all three other versions of the file* remain in the index, in slot 1 (which is merely numbered), slot 2 (available via `git checkout --ours`), and slot 3 (available via `git checkout --theirs).  You can therefore obtain any or all three versions of the file into the work-tree using`git checkout`or`git show`:

```
git show :1:file > file.base
git show :2:file > file.head
git checkout --theirs file   # overwrite work-tree version
```

for instance.

Once you have resolved the merge conflict in the work-tree, you run `git add file` to copy `file` into slot zero, wiping out the slot 1, 2, and 3 entries.  Once *all* such files are resolved, you run `git rebase --continue` (if rebasing, or `git cherry-pick --continue` if cherry-picking) to have Git commit the result from the index as usual.

For rebase, the next step would be to copy commit `B`:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C   <-- yourbranch
         \
          D--E   <-- target
              \
               A'  <-- HEAD
```

This copying is done as if by `git cherry-pick`, which mean that the merge base is commit `A`, the `--ours` commit is commit `A'`, and the `--theirs` commit is commit `B`.  If there is a merge conflict, those are the three versions of the file that you will find in the index.

After resolving this conflict and running `git rebase --continue`, you'll have this if the cherry-pick of commit `C` stops with a conflict:

```
...--o--*--A--B--C   <-- yourbranch
         \
          D--E   <-- target
              \
               A'-B'  <-- HEAD
```

and now the three index versions will be those from the merge base `B`, the `--ours` commit `B'`, and the `--theirs` commit `C`.

Hence, the files you want *are* available.  They're just in the *index*, not the work-tree.

Comment: git cherry-pick is cool and much more intuitive than git rebase, but I don't understand, why git devs doesn't make git rebase more user-friendly by returning the changes somewhere else. If the conflict is in hundreds of files, I don't want to open all files and search the special characters git rebase uses to fix the file. And also I always forget some special characters from git rebase in files. And usually when I open the file, I don't understand the git rebase special characters and markers. It is real pain.

Comment: @aleskva: Once you have `git cherry-pick` internalized properly, `git rebase` becomes easy, because it's simply *repeated cherry-pick* (followed at the end by a branch-label move).

Comment: Yeah, but rebase edits the files on conflict in a really bad manner, which is always a pain for me

Comment: I recommend setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`: it's not a huge help but I find it more readable. In your case, though, you might benefit from some outside-Git merge tool(s). The `git mergetool` command can run such things, although `git mergetool` itself is pretty crude and clumsy. I don't do this myself but it's worth experimenting. Search for "git merge tools".

Comment: conflictStyle seems to be a cool idea, but both options are not really user-friendly. I already switched to git mergetool, meld to be specific. But I found out this option is available like 4 years after solving git conflicts by hand.